# How to change the contents of a file by using Puppet?

Tags: puppet

I have a html file and I want to use Puppet to replace that file with an empty file with the same filename. I am wondering if it is possible for Puppet to delete the whole contents of a file?

E.g. Is this a correct way to delete a line in Puppet?

```
file_line { 'delete a line':
 ensure => absent,
 path => /tmp/test,
 line => '\ '
 match => '^(?:.*)'
}
```

Comment: It is possible.  Use a `File` resource with `content => ''`.  `File_line` is for exactly one line, even if there are multiple lines it could match in the specified file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you know there is a file `/path/to/file.html` and you want to ensure that that file exists and is empty, it's easy:

```
file { '/path/to/file.html':
  ensure  => file,
  content => '',
}
```

If you want to ensure that a line in that file is removed using `file_line`, you have two ways of doing this when `ensure => absent` is set.

One is to set `match => ...` and `match_for_absence => true`,
as in the following example:

```
file_line { 'bashrc_proxy':
  ensure            => absent,
  path              => '/etc/bashrc',
  match             => '^export\ HTTP_PROXY\=',
  match_for_absence => true,
}
```

In this code example match will look for a line beginning with export
followed by HTTP_PROXY and delete it.  If multiple lines match, an
error will be raised unless the `multiple => true` parameter is set.

Note that the `line => ...` parameter would be accepted *but ignored* in
the above example.

The second way of using `ensure => absent` is to specify a `line => ...`,
and no match:

```
file_line { 'bashrc_proxy':
  ensure => absent,
  path   => '/etc/bashrc',
  line   => 'export HTTP_PROXY=http://squid.puppetlabs.vm:3128',
}
```

Note that when ensuring lines are absent this way, the default behavior
this time is to always remove all lines matching, and this behavior
can't be disabled.

See also in the code [here](https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppetlabs-stdlib/blob/master/lib/puppet/provider/file_line/ruby.rb#L38-L44) and [here](https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppetlabs-stdlib/blob/master/lib/puppet/provider/file_line/ruby.rb#L122-L140) and in the unit tests.

I have also raised a pull request to add these examples of `file_line` into the official docs [here](https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppetlabs-stdlib/pull/820%08), as this was not adequately documented before.

Thanks for the question.

Comment: Thank you very much! Your answer helped me to solve my problem :)

Comment: Is it possible to say do this operation for any line, without specifying the contents of line (such as: line   => 'export HTTP_PROXY=http://squid.puppetlabs.vm:3128') ?

Comment: Well that's the whole point of the :match parameter, as I explained.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "any match". Can you show exactly what you are passing to match?

Comment: It's possible you should ask a new question, in which case I'll happily answer it.

Comment: replace => false fixed the problem.